# Rearranging data in R for market basket analysis

Tags: r, market-basket-analysis

I have data available in csv format.

Data format is as follows. With Receipt nos in one column and Product in the corresponding column

```
Receipt_no Product
A1  Apple
A1  Banana
A1  Orange
A2  Pineapple
A2  Jackfruit
A3  Cola
A3  Tea
```

I want to rearrange them as

```
A1 ,  Apple, Banana, Orange
A2 , Pineapple, Jackfruit
A3 , Cola, Tea
```

That is the receipt numbers and product names in one row separated by comma. Since the data is large I want to rearrange the same in R .

Kindly help

Thanks.

Regards,
Nithish

Comment: Can you please reply whether any of the below works for you?

Comment: Soto's reply was good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R,

```
aggregate(Product ~ Receipt_no, df, paste, collapse = ',')
```

Using `dplyr`,

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Receipt_no) %>% 
  summarise(new = paste(Product, collapse = ','))
```

Comment: I have 750000 rows of data. I used he baseR function you suggested. Can we estimate the time in advance to execute it  ?

Comment: I am not sure you can do that. There is a function called `Sys.time` but It will have to run the script. However, the fastest you will be able to achieve is with `data.table`. You can easily translate my above code to `data.table`

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
u <- as.vector(unique(df$Receipt_no))
as.list(sapply(u, function(x) paste0(x, ", ", paste0(subset(df$Product, df$Receipt_no==x), collapse = ", "))))

# $A1
# [1] "A1, Apple, Banana, Orange"

# $A2
# [1] "A2, Pineapple, Jackfruit"

# $A3
# [1] "A3, Cola, Tea"
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Receipt_no = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("A1", "A2", "A3"), class = "factor"), Product = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 7L), .Label = c("Apple", "Banana", "Cola", 
"Jackfruit", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Tea"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Receipt_no", 
"Product"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```